# Taking the limit of ratios of interpolation error

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, derivatives, sobolev-spaces

I don't know how to take the limit of the ratio of two functional error estimates, when both go to zero in particular
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{h \| u - u_h\|^2_{L^2(\partial \kappa)} }{ \| u - u_h\|^2_{L^2(\kappa)} }
$$

where $h$ is the diameter of $\kappa$ and $u_h = \arg \inf_{v\in \mathbb{P}^p} \|u - v\|_{L^2(\kappa)}$, and $\mathbb{P}^p(\kappa)$ is the set of polynomials of order less than or equal to $p$.

From computation I have pretty good reason to believe that this gives a constant value for sufficiently smooth $u$.

Right now I have, using the trace inequality, 
\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{h \| u - u_h\|^2_{L^2(\partial \kappa)} }{ \| u - u_h\|^2_{L^2(\kappa)} } &\leq \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{h \| u - u_h\|_{L^2(\kappa)}\| u - u_h\|_{H^1(\kappa)} }{ \| u - u_h\|^2_{L^2(\kappa)} }\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{h \| u - u_h\|_{H^1(\kappa)} }{ \| u - u_h\|_{L^2(\kappa)} }
\end{align}

but I am stuck after that, and am unsure if this is a sensible approach.

**EDITS:**
$$\| u - u_h \|^2_{L^2(\kappa)} = \int_{\kappa} (u - u_h)^2 dx $$ $\kappa$ is a non-degenerate simplex, and $\partial\kappa$ is the boundary of $\kappa$.

**Simplified 1D version**: I am fairly numerically convinced the answer is $4(p+\frac{3}{2})$

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ h \left( (u-u_h)^2(x_M + \frac{h}{2}) +(u-u_h)^2(x_M - \frac{h}{2}) \right) }{ \int^{x_M + \frac{h}{2}}_{x_M - \frac{h}{2}} (u-u_h)^2 dx }
$$

*Note*: This comes from looking for the value of 
$$
 \frac{\partial}{\partial h} \log \left( \int^{x_M + \frac{h}{2}}_{x_M - \frac{h}{2}} (u-u_h)^2 dx  \right)
$$

Comment: One piece of your notation would benefit from an explanation, the norms $||\cdot||_{L^2(\kappa)}$ and variations.  I suppose that $\kappa$ here denotes a region and $\partial \kappa$ its boundary, but that is worth making explicit.

Comment: Yes, sorry
$\| u - u_h \|^2_{L^2(\kappa)} = \int_{\kappa} (u - u_h)^2 dx $

Comment: We will need some assumptions about the region $\kappa$ and its boundary, so these notes should be added, perhaps tersely, to the body of your Question.

Comment: I think it would depend on the equation you are solving and the domain, and I must say also the kind of polynomials used!

Comment: Simplest one:

$u = e^x$, $p=1$ Lagrange basis, a single line $[-1,1]$.

Comment: The one-dimensional interval  $\kappa$ case is perhaps not very interesting since the boundary will consist only of its endpoints, which can be exactly interpolated for $p=1$ and higher.

Comment: $u_h$ is defined by L2 interpolation on the volume however, so the end points won't be exact unless $u$ is linear within the interior. It turned out that I can almost do this entirely analytically using the Reynolds Transport Theorem.